# Is single threaded process contains only one thread?

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, single-threaded

Can someone give more explain for single-threaded and multi-threaded processes

Is single threaded process contains only one thread? or it means that that process can contain multiple threads and can run only one thread at a time, then context-switch between them?
If i run a java program on a single core processor is the second one would be true?

Can someone explain it further?

Comment: Single CPU or core vs multi-CPU is orthogonal to how many threads are in a process (all four options are available).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single-threaded process is a process with a single thread.  A multi-threaded process is a process with multiple threads.

The naming is based on the static configuration, i.e. you could look at the process when execution is suspended and say if it's single-threaded or multi-threaded.  Whether or not the threads are executed on a single core or multiple cores doesn't matter as far as the nomenclature goes.

A process with multiple threads all executing on a single core can have race conditions, as can a process with multiple threads executing across multiple cores.  Distinguishing the two situations is important for performance evaluation but counter-productive for correctness (i.e. it's useful to assume that each thread is on a separate CPU when considering potential races).

A single-threaded *program* is a *program* that only uses one thread.  The *process* might have additional threads; for your example of the Java runtime, you can expect to have a finalizer thread and perhaps one or more threads for garbage collection.  It's a single-threaded *program* running in a multi-threaded *process*.

(I've heard "process" defined as "the abstraction of a program in execution", i.e. you write a program and then execute it in a process.)

Answer (score 0):

Single threaded does not mean single-core, single process.
Single threaded processes contain the execution of instructions in a single sequence. In other words, one command is processes at a time